# How to deal with a presentModal inside a tabBar that needs to use navigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to push a view controller inside a presentmodal but nothing happening. So, I have a loginController as rootViewController that push a tabBarControler then inside one of tabBar views I open a presentModal. In the presentModal I have an UITableView when clicked push another view but when I try do this nothing happen. To try be more clear here's the hierarchy:

LoginViewController(as root view controller) >>>push>>> UITabBarController(HomeViewController and two others) >>>open>>> PackViewController(presentModal) that needs to open another view by pushViewController:

The code:

AppDelegate.m

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

LoginViewController_iPhone *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController_iPhone alloc] init];

self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController] autorelease];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

LoginViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

HomeViewController_iPhone *referenciaHomeViewController = [[HomeViewController_iPhone alloc] init];
MapaViewController_iPhone *referenciaMapaViewController = [[MapaViewController_iPhone alloc] init];
GuiaViewController_iPhone *referenciaMidiaViewController = [[GuiaViewController_iPhone alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navHome = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:referenciaHomeViewController];
UINavigationController *navMapa = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:referenciaMapaViewController];
UINavigationController *navGuia = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:referenciaMidiaViewController];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarBackground"]];
[self.tabBarController.tabBar  setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabBarSelected"]];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navHome, navMapa, navGuia, nil];

}

- (void)login {

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabBarController animated:YES];

}
```

PackViewController.m (PRESENTMODAL):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

CompraPackViewController_iPhone *controller = [[CompraPackViewController_iPhone alloc] init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do your present modal, you need to present a navigation controller whose root view controller is the table view controller.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant. Can you try to put in other words?

Comment: @LucasBrito, You just need to add one step. currently, when you do the present modal, you create an instance of PackViewController and then present it, right? You need to insert a step in between those two. Instantiate a UINavigationController (using initWithRootViewController:) with the PackViewController as its root view controller, then present that navigation controller.